# mongodb: restart after removing lock file

Tags: macos, bash, mongodb, shell

I'm on OS/X Macbook and recently installed mongodb to try my hands on it. I installed it using shell commands. I scrapped some data and passed into it and when I tried looking for it, the connection was getting failed. On googling the root cause, I found there was some `mongodb.lock` file, and I removed it using bash command. 
Now, I'm trying to restart using the following command

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

However, it is saying

> sudo: service: command not found

in addition, if I start mongodb by navigating to folder and then using the command `./bin/mongo`, it displays the following error:

> MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
>   connecting to: test
>   2015-11-08T14:47:56.965+0800 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
>   2015-11-08T14:47:56.967+0800 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
>       at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
>       at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
>   exception: connect failed

can someone please help how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no `service` command on Mac. And `./bin/mongo` runs a shell client, you need to run `.bin/mongod` with relevant `--dbpath` argument. You can find more info [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

1. Like Yuri wrote, there is no `service` command on OS X. You need to manage MongoDB yourself by starting it with the `mongod` command.
2. An Alternative is to install MongoDB via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org).
   After you successfully installed MacPorts, you simply install MongoDB with

   ```
   sudo port install mongodb
   ```

   You can start MongoDB quite easily then with

   ```
   sudo port load mongodb
   ```

   and stop it with

   ```
   sudo port unload mongodb
   ```
3. `mongo` is the client. You haven't had the server running, so it is only natural that you can not connect to the server.

Some side note: OS X is not very close to Linux. OS X  is based on a flavor of BSD-UNIX, which in turn is based on [Research UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_Unix). Linux started as a free implementation of Minix, based on GNU utilities. So assuming that you'd have Linux tools available on the OS X command line is pretty dangerous. Often, the tools (if present) even share the name, but are different implementations of the same functionality with some differences in usage. So, get it in your head: With OS X, you do not use the hipster version of Linux – you use BSD on steroids. Hence, I will remove the "linux" tag and add the OS X tag.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm able to resolve the issue, but when I try stopping the server on mongo shell with command ` use admin` `db.shutdownServer()` , it gives me error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017. May I know why this is happening. I'm able to write json file before shutting down, I think, this means that the server was running before

Comment: @user4943236 Exactly. The shell simply tells you it can not connect any more. Mission accomplished.